# MongoDB GetDate Syntax

Tags: mongodb

In SQL Server while trying to insert records you have the option to specify

```
GETDATE()-1, GETDATE()
```

I tried below statement for MongoDB

```
db.TableA.insert({Name:ABC,SaleDate:this.date.getDate-1,SaleValue:2500,City:XYZ})
```

This does not work. What is the MongoDB equivalent syntax to insert `getDate` value for a table column?

I am also looking into [MongoDB documentation](http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/date_range/), but I am still figuring it out.

Answer (score 1):

Just typing "new Date()" should do it.

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dates